# Error while migrating a Joomla website from version 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: php, migration

I have tried to migrate a website in Joomla from version 1.5 to 2.5 using jUpgrade but I received an "undefined migrating" error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown column 'rawpassword' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `j25_users` (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`rawpassword`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`,`activation`,`params`,`newsletter`,`blog`) VALUES ('62','Administrator','idnadmin','webmaster@idnxchange.com','a67042770b2ebf18e330abbef9453a06:LKQiBAD5PjxFacEoXzHLSV7uhIAEfNGX','','Super Administrator','0','1','2011-06-09 23:43:07','2014-07-07 04:17:19','66b5d829f602c13165caecbe88d4f19f:RDRr56vAoRMkaVaQUnjRacD1xiCkDNgM','{\"admin_language\""\",\"language\""\",\"editor\""\",\"helpsite\""\",\"timezone\""UTC\"}','0','1')' in /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/jupgrade.class.php:347 Stack trace: #0 /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/controller.php(45): jUpgrade->upgrade() #1 {main} thrown in /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/jupgrade.class.php on line 347
==========
[undefined] [undefined]
```

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters on SE. This is a great bunch of folks here. I do not know Jommla, but clearly this is a database schema incompatibility. There is a missing column on table j25_users. Is there possibly a required intermediate upgrade?

Comment: What is your current version of Joomla?

Answer (score 3):

Joomla 1.5's users table structure was this:
http://www.torkiljohnsen.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/joomla_15_database_schema.png

And 3 is this
http://docs.joomla.org/Tables/users

It looks like somewhere "rawpassword", "blog" and "newsletter" have been added to your database.  My guess would be that you've installed a badly-coded extension that has changed the core database, since I can find no reference to these ever having been part of Joomla.

To narrow the problem down, I'd perhaps download your site and do a text search in the files for "rawpassword" to see if you can find the offending extension - see if there is a .sql file that adds it.

(NB For security, I would recommend you remove the username and password value fields in the error message you have posted)

Answer (score 0):

Column rawpassword does not exist in 2.5. I am guessing it existed in 1.5. You can manually create such a column in the backend for 2.5 and continue with the upgrade. Once upgrade is done, delete that column.

I haven't actually tried this but it might work. If you have a backup of 1.5 before upgrade, there is no harm trying things out.